# How much currency/cash can be carried in while travelling to India in flight?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, india, money, hungary

I am an Indian and now in Hungary. How much euro's can I carry with me in flight when I travel back to India?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As much as you'd like. But, if it's a real lot, you might need to declare it.

[When leaving Hungary](http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/HU-Hungary-customs-currency-airport-tax-regulations-details.htm)

> amounts exceeding EUR 10,000.- or more or the equivalent in another currency (incl. banker's draft and cheques of any kind) must be declared.

[When arriving to India](http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/IN-India-customs-currency-airport-tax-regulations-details.htm)

> amounts exceeding USD 5,000.- (or equivalent) in cash, or USD 10,000.- (or equivalent) in traveller's cheques must be declared;
>   Local currency (Indian Rupee-INR): Import of INR is prohibited, except for residents of India importing up to INR 7,500.-
>
> Foreign currencies include currency notes, traveller's cheques, cheques, drafts etc.

Edit: for future readers, make sure to check when this answer was updated last as I personally expect these numbers to be lowered soon-ish.